# Does a Swiss Pass entitle me to any discounts when leaving Switzerland?

Tags: trains, switzerland

The [Swiss Pass](http://www.raileurope.com/rail-tickets-passes/swiss-pass/index.html) entitles foreign travellers to unlimited travel in Switzerland, including the Bernina Express to my surprise (it does not include the small seat reservation fee).  Given that travels from Italy into Switzerland, I was wondering whether the Swiss Pass also covers other routes out of Switzerland.

I'm specifically interested in finding out if there are ways to get a cheaper fare from Zurich to Luxembourg using a Swiss Pass, either by covering part of the trip or provide a discount of some form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.swisstravelsystem.com/en/home/support/Frequently-Asked-Questions.html):

> **Which ticket do I require for international arrivals or departures? Are Swiss Travel System tickets valid on these trains? Are reductions available?**
>   Swiss Travel System tickets are valid only on the national route network of the STS. For international arrivals and departures, separate tickets are required. When booking an international ticket to Switzerland, you can (under "Reduction") deduct from the international point-to-point fare that part of your journey covered by the Swiss Travel System ticket in your possession.

Please read the corresponding text in the FAQ under the "traveling to Switzerland" section.

In short: You will get the swiss part of the international ticket for free, but you have to make sure you book it correctly to get the discount. If you do not need to reserve a seat, you can always only book the the tickets outside of Switzerland.